# Pipe chaining in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using `*ngFor` in which I am trying to use multiple pipes, but I can't seem to make it work.

```html
<tr *ngFor="let order of orders | filter:filter; let i=index | paginate: {itemsPerPage:7 , currentPage:p}">
```

When I use one pipe either one it works fine. But when I try to use both, I get this error:

> Can't bind to ngForFilter since it is not a known property of tr

Comment: you can write a custom pipe for the same!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems like your order is off. I might be wrong but try this syntax with the pipes as the last part and make sure index follow orders:

```js
<tr *ngFor="let order of orders; let i=index | filter:filter | paginate: {itemsPerPage:7 , currentPage:p}">
```

Let me know if that works. Cheers